# PHP with pdo-mysql in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, php

I've been trying to install php (7.2) in Ubuntu (16.04) with PDO enabled. I don't need php as apache module, because I want to use PHPs built-in server (in cli mode, like `php -S localhost:80`).

So, here is what i do:

`sudo apt-get install php`

`sudo apt-get install php-mysql`

`sudo cp /usr/lib/php/7.2/php.ini-production.cli /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini`

Now, in php.ini uncommented:

`extension=pdo_mysql`

And still when i run `php -v` I get the error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params)) in Unknown on line 0
```

`php -m` output:

```
[PHP Modules]
Core
date
filter
hash
libxml
openssl
pcntl
pcre
Reflection
session
sodium
SPL
standard
zlib
[Zend Modules]
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42929132/299774

Comment: `sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql` gives me `/usr/sbin/phpenmod: 31: .: Can't open /usr/lib/php/php-helper`

Comment: answer above says that in ubuntu 16.04 you don't need to enable the mod, try just install + restart.

Comment: oh, wait - you do it in CLI, no apache restart should be needed in this case.

Comment: Yes, apache2 is inactive

Comment: How did you install PHP 7.2?

Comment: @fkraiem `sudo apt-get install php`

Comment: In 16.04, that does not give you PHP 7.2. You must have added a PPA or something.

Answer (score 40):

I solved the problem this way:

`sudo apt-get --purge remove php-common`

`sudo apt-get install php-common php-mysql php-cli`

Now there is no error and `php -m` shows it has everything:

```
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
date
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Still don't know what caused the issue in the first place

Comment: I had the same problem with Debian and PHP 7.2 (5.6, 7.0, 7.1 and 7.3 were working fine) Purging and installing anew solved it for me too

Comment: solved my `xampp` problem in ubuntu 16.04 . Thanks

Comment: Saved me from a weird PHP installation

Comment: Yay - worked for me too

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. (Ubuntu 19.04 | Php 7.2)

Comment: This didn't work for me. It removed  `phpMyAdmin`. I couldn't run `phpunit` anymore .. I had to remove `PHP` totally and try installing it again. Also `Apache2` didn't start successfully.

Comment: Thank you. For Drupal 8 users: I also had to add a few more modules to get my Drupal 8 requirements taken care of: `sudo apt-get install php-xml` and `sudo apt-get install php-gd` and `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring` but after that I got Drupal working. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

I created the same issue for myself on my work box by manually uncommenting several

```
;extension=<module>
```

lines in the `php.ini`.  Which was really me second-guessing the `apt-get install` process. I think modern php7+ handles these extensions using `conf.d` specific files like:

- `/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini`
- `/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini`

The answer then for me was re-commenting these `;extension` lines in the cli's `php.ini` file.